# Search Center url renamed, but subsite search takes to old search center url page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I have renamed the enterprise search center url from 
`/xxxxx/Search` to `/xxxxx/WebSearch`

Search from root site top navigation search dropdown takes to `https://xxxxx/WebSearch`, which is good. But search from any subsite takes it to `https://xxxxx/Search` and we get page not found error. How to fix this without going to each subsite and doing any changes, because we have a lot of subsites in the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Search Service Application. There is a setting for the Global Search Center URL. It is likely pointing to the old location.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your sub-site settings are set to inherit from Parent then it will automatically update it. Another way is use the powershell to update for all at once.

```
function SetSearchSettingsSite($siteUrl,$searchCenterUrl,$resultPagesUrl)
{
 $site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
 $site.AllWebs | ForEach-Object {
 $web = $_
 $web.AllProperties["SRCH_SB_SET_WEB"] = '{"Inherit":false,"ResultsPageAddress":"'+$resultPagesUrl+'","ShowNavigation":false}'
 $web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_WEB"] = $searchCenterUrl
 $web.Update()
 }
}
```

Read more about above code here: [Update Search Settings using Powershell in SharePoint 2013](https://radutut.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/update-search-settings-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Also check this one http://sharepoint.jsturges.com/2012/02/update-search-center-for-all-sites-in-a-web-application/

Comment: Thanks. Subsites are already inheriting from parent. I disabled and enabled inheritting manually for a subsite, it  didnt work. I can try the script in the links.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
$spSitecollection="https://xxxx.com"
$webs= get-spsite $spSitecollection | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | where {$_.serverrelativeurl -ne "/xxxSearch"} | select serverrelativeurl


foreach ($element in $webs) {
       $relURL="$spSitecollection$($element.serverrelativeurl)"
       $web=get-spweb $relURL
       $web
    #delete existing link
    $navItems=@();
       $navs = $web.Navigation.SearchNav
       foreach ($nav in $navs)
       {
             $nodeid =$web.Navigation.GetNodeById($nav.Id)
             $navItems+=$nodeid
             write-host "$($nodeid.title) add id $($nodeid.Id) to array"  
       }   
       foreach ($node in $navItems)
       {
             $web.Navigation.SearchNav.delete($node)
             write-host "delete id $($node.Id)"    
       }     
       $web.update()       
$titleTHISSITE="This Site"
       $relativeURLTHISSITE=$element.serverrelativeurl + "/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=$($relURL)"
       $nodeTHISSITE=new-object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode" -ArgumentList $TitleTHISSITE, $RelativeUrlTHISSITE, $true 
       $web.Navigation.SearchNav.AddAsLast($nodeTHISSITE)
       $titleEVERYTHING="Everything"
       $relativeURLEVERYTHING=$serverrelativeurl + "/xxxSearch/Pages/results.aspx"
       $nodeEVERYTHING=new-object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode" -ArgumentList $TitleEVERYTHING, $RelativeUrlEVERYTHING, $true 
       $web.Navigation.SearchNav.AddAsLast($nodeEVERYTHING) 

}
```